# sql grouping finding average

Tags: mysql, sql

i am looking to find the avg cost for the total cost of each order but my grouping function is invalid

```
SELECT AVG(SUM(quantityOrdered*priceEach)) AS total 
FROM orderdetails od 
GROUP BY orderNumber
```

below is a snippet of my database

```
orderNumber productCode quantityOrdered priceEach orderLineNumber
10100       S24_3969                 49     35.29               1
10101       S18_2325                 25    108.06               4
10101       S18_2795                 26    167.06               1
10101       S24_1937                 45     32.53               3
10101       S24_2022                 46     44.35               2
10102       S18_1342                 39     95.55               2
10102       S18_1367                 41     43.13               1
10103       S10_1949                 26    214.3               11
10103       S10_4962                 42    119.67               4
10103       S12_1666                 27    121.64               8
10103       S18_1097                 35     94.5               10
10103       S18_2432                 22     58.34               2
10103       S18_2949                 27     92.19              12
10103       S18_2957                 35     61.84              14
10103       S18_3136                 25     86.92              13
10103       S18_3320                 46     86.31              16
```

Comment: Toggle caps-lock and try again.

Comment: @jarlh Very funny :-)

Comment: Actually not that bad writing all that without watching the screen once.

Comment: What is your desired output?  The error you are getting has to do with nesting aggregate functions.  You can't say `AVG(SUM(something))`, this won't work.  But besides that, does it even make logical sense?

Comment: i am doing it for college it makes no sense in my mind, i have to compare the sum of each order to the average order sum and if its greater display the sum of that order

Comment: the question is 'Using the classicmodels schema. List the
customerName, custmoerNumber and combined price
of all the customers payments. Where the combined
total of a customers payemts is greater than the
average spent by a customer.' I have completed all other parts besides comparing to the average

Comment: Please edit the question accordingly. Is "combined price" the same as "total"? Maybe something's been lost in translation.

Comment: Your question doesnt include the whole schema, there isnt `customerName or customerNumber`

Comment: @Strawberry How you convert the image in text?

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza I use MS OneNote for that - and a text editor to adjust the formatting

Comment: @Strawberry But you do it by hand or have some kind of OCR function?

Answer (score 0):

It's invalid use cannot use two aggregate functions together

```
    SELECT SUM(quantityOrdered*priceEach) AS total
    FROM orderdetails od 
    GROUP BY orderNumber
    Having  SUM(quantityOrdered*priceEach)>(SELECT  AVG(quantityOrdered*priceEach) FROM orderdetails)
```

Answer (score 0):

You do it in two steps.

**[SQL Fiddle Demo](https://rextester.com/ZWS28089)**

- Calculate the Total of each order.

  ```
    SELECT orderNumber, SUM(quantityOrdered*priceEach) AS total 
    FROM orderdetails od 
    GROUP BY orderNumber
  ```
- Calculate the Average between all the totals

  ```
   SELECT AVG(total)
   FROM ( SELECT orderNumber, SUM(quantityOrdered*priceEach) AS total 
          FROM orderdetails od 
          GROUP BY orderNumber
        ) T
  ```

**EDIT**: I miss the last step after checking Ritesh answer.

```
SELECT o.*, t.global_avg
FROM (SELECT orderNumber, SUM(quantityOrdered*priceEach) AS order_total 
      FROM orderdetails od 
      GROUP BY orderNumber) o
CROSS JOIN       
     (SELECT AVG(total) global_avg
      FROM ( SELECT orderNumber, SUM(quantityOrdered*priceEach) AS total 
             FROM orderdetails od 
             GROUP BY orderNumber
            ) t
      ) t
WHERE o.order_total > t.global_avg;
```

**OUTPUT:**

[image]

Comment: is the avg(total) meant to be 117764.2500 or 11764,2500

Comment: `,` is  a decimal separator in rextester. btw you can use Gordon version to calculate average, is simpler than mine.

Answer (score 0):

Just calculate the average using `sum()` divided by a number:

```
SELECT SUM(quantityOrdered*priceEach) / COUNT(DISTINCT orderNumber) AS total 
FROM orderdetails od ;
```

Comment: Your avg is definitly simpler than mine, but avg was just part of the problem OP also want select orders with `order_total > avg_total` in case you want expand it.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza . . . I'm responding to the question in the *question*.  Because questions should be asked in a comment, the OP is advised to ask another question.